# Accessing elements associated with data using D3 after they have been generated

Tags: d3.js

I have a dataset, each item has been linked to svg rects using D3.

```
var bars = svg_content.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset);
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
```

Assume the generation is complete (i.e. the .enter() process is complete and the rects have been generated).

How would I access the rect associated with a specific index of that dataset (for instance, the rect linked to the third piece of data)?

Comment: you could always say d3.selectAll("rect")[2] and this will provide you with third "rect"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) or the function form of the commonly used [selection.select](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-select) depending on your needs:

```js
var third = selection.filter(function(d, i) { return i == 2; });

// Equivalently
var third = selection.select(function(d, i) { return i == 2; });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. Generally, in d3, you tend to access the data from within a selection. So you would see something like:

```js
var bars = svg_content.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset);
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr('class', function(d) { return d.myName; });
```

Here d is the data item from dataset that is associated with a particular rect. That code would class each rect with the "myName" property of each data item.

Let's say some you want to place one of these rects specially. One with `myName='aName'`. We will select that rectangle and set the 'tranform' attribute based on the associated data.

```js
svg.content.selectAll('rect.aName')
    .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 20 ')'; })
```

Note that in both cases you can also access the item's index and if it's relevant also the parent index (use `function(d,i,j) {...}`)

Finally, though I don't encourage it in general, I have for unit tests directly accessed the data associated with an element with `__data__`. For example with jQuery:

```js
$.find("svg rect.aName")[0].__data__;
```

You can play with a quick fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/superboggly/aa2kU/1/)